# Coping selected Filtered Data to a new sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have some code to filter data and copy into a new sheet.

I am having some difficulty in coping all of the required columns at once and was wondering if someone could help me on this. There are 2 sources and 2 destinations in the new sheet. Could someone please point me in the right direction? I have only included 1 half of the macro here as I have not finished the other part due to being stuck on this.

I am also struggling to use the "Insurer" that I have set at the top of the code to populate the "Insurer" name in the file save as, in as ABC here, is this possible or would I have to hard code it? I was looking to set this off in a loop running through a list of companies that I need to create the file for

```
Dim LR As Integer
Dim Insurer As Integer
Dim InsurerNew As Integer
Dim InsurerOld As Integer




LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AD" & LR).AutoFilter Field:=22, Criteria1:=Insurer

Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
    "G:\Accounts\FINANCE\Financial Data\Bordereau\Monthly Bordereau\CDL Insurer Template.xlsx"

If Application.Subtotal(103, .Columns(3)) > 1 Then
    .Columns(1).Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Copy _
      Destination:=Workbooks("CDL Insurer Template.xls").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    .Columns(2).Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Copy _
     Destination:=Workbooks("CDL Insurer Template.xls").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    .Columns(3).Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Copy _
      Destination:=Workbooks("CDL Insurer Template.xls").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
     .Columns(4).Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Copy _
     Destination:=Workbooks("CDL Insurer Template.xls").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
      .Columns(5).Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Copy _
     Destination:=Workbooks("CDL Insurer Template.xls").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
     .Columns(6).Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Copy _
     Destination:=Workbooks("CDL Insurer Template.xls").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
     .Columns(7).Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Copy _
     Destination:=Workbooks("CDL Insurer Template.xls").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
     .Columns(8).Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Copy _
     Destination:=Workbooks("CDL Insurer Template.xls").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
     .Columns(9).Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Copy _
     Destination:=Workbooks("CDL Insurer Template.xls").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
     .Columns(10).Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Copy _
     Destination:=Workbooks("CDL Insurer Template.xls").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
     .Columns(11).Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Copy _
     Destination:=Workbooks("CDL Insurer Template.xls").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 11).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
     .Columns(12).Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Copy _
     Destination:=Workbooks("CDL Insurer Template.xls").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 12).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

ChDir "G:\Accounts\FINANCE\Financial Data\Bordereau\Monthly Bordereau\2015-03"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "G:\Accounts\FINANCE\Financial Data\Bordereau\Monthly Bordereau\2015-03\ABC 2015-03.xlsx" _
    , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
```

Thanks

Steven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is completely ***UNTESTED***, but it should at least give you the idea...

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyColumns()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim insurer As Integer
    Dim dataRange As Range
    Dim subT As Range
    Dim newWB As Workbook
    Dim fName As String
    Dim fPath As String

    '--- determine the range of the data and filter it for the requested insurer
    lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set dataRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("$A$1:$AD" & lastRow)
    insurer = 1
    dataRange.AutoFilter Field:=22, Criteria1:="=" & insurer

    '--- open the empty workbook template as the destination for the copied data
    Set newWB = Workbooks.Open("G:\Accounts\FINANCE\Financial Data\Bordereau\Monthly Bordereau\CDL Insurer Template.xlsx")

    '--- check the subtotal and copy the range only if the subtotal is more than 1
    '    (put the SUBTOTAL formula in the cell to make it easier)\
    Set subT = dataRange.Cells(lastRow + 1, 3)
    subT.Formula = "=SUBTOTAL(103," & dataRange.Offset(1, 2).Resize(lastRow - 1, 1).Address & ")"
    If subT.Value > 1 Then
        dataRange.Resize(lastRow, 12).Copy Destination:=newWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    End If

    '--- set up the workbook to save to the correct location
    fPath = "G:\Accounts\FINANCE\Financial Data\Bordereau\Monthly Bordereau\2015-03\"
    fName = "ABC 2015-03.xlsx"
    newWB.SaveAs fPath & fName
    newWB.Close

End Sub
```